# how to call a window's Loaded event in WPF MVVM?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, window, onload

It is easy enough to create a command from my OnLoaded() event
handler code, but how do I call it from the View?

**<window Loaded="onLoaded">** doesn't cut the cake anymore since
it calls code in the xaml.cs. How would I create an ICommand 
equivalent?

Answer (score 10):

You can do this sort of thing via an attached behavior. To save yourself some time, take a looked at Marlon Grech's [Attached Command Behavior](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/) library.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the MVVM Light Toolkit's event to command behavior:
http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/11/05/mvvm-light-toolkit-v3-alpha-2-eventtocommand-behavior.aspx

Comment: For anyone using the MVVM light toolkit (or considering it), this worked well for me.