# Load model data in background

Tags: mvvm, prism

I am developing a Prism application where I need to load some data in the model in the background after the application has loaded. I have a separate view which is hidden which would show this data via a view model. I dont want to increase the application load time and neither do I want to increase the view load time. The only solution I could think of is to raise a `Shell Loaded` event and let the view model or model subscribe to it.

Is this a good approach or is there a better approach?

Also, I am not sure whether I should raise the `Shell Loaded` event in the `Run` of the `Bootstrapper` or in the `Shell ViewModel`. How do I link a routed command (for ex: Loaded) to an `ICommand`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to avoid to handle these kinds of events in the bootstrapper. So attaching the Loaded event of the shell view to the shell view model is a good way to go. The only reason to actually raise this event in the bootstrapper is if you need the StartupEventArgs (which I sometimes do).

There are quite a few ways of handling the loaded event.

- 100% MVVM use an attached property that passes the event straight to an ICommand or method. Ex: [how to call a window's Loaded event in WPF MVVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222704/how-to-call-a-windows-loaded-event-in-wpf-mvvm)
- Just handle the Loaded event it in the code behind and call the Loaded method / Command in the VM from there. This a simple and easy solution to get started.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce loading time, you should try to avoid putting too much work on the UI thread. You may want to investigate the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) or a nice framework called [ReactiveUI](http://www.reactiveui.net/) which provides a very convient mechanism to load things asynchronously.